# Develop iOS 17 apps from MacBook Pro 2017

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to develop iOS 17 apps with a MacBook Pro from 2017 (Intel)?

I've been using an M1 machine that I don't have anymore and I have iOS 17 specific apps that I can't develop anymore since the latest Xcode I can get is version 14.3.1.

Is there a way I can put the iOS 17 SDK inside?

Comment: No, you need a newer Mac. You need to be able to install Ventura or Sonoma to get Xcode 15

Comment: @Paulw11, you only need mac to think it's new. There're ways to install macOS Ventura (that allows Xcode 15 installation) even on macBooks from 2008. But they are risky ofc, and performance may be not so great.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a five-year-old pro machine can no longer be used for development according to Apple. Probably because of environmental awareness...

I don't recommend tricky macOS installations either. App Store upload will not work.

Comment: You can easily install Sonoma and Xcode 15 on a 5-year old Mac. But the question is asking about a 2017 Mac. That's 7 years old, not 5.

Comment: It was sold between 2017-2019